# Swift - How could I iterate over all possibilities of a collection of stridable variables

Tags: swift, reflection, mirror

I have a configuration defined with various ranges and would like to iterate over all the possibilities without coding it explicitly.

My guess is to use reflection but perhaps there is an easier way?

here is an example:

```
struct Settings {
    var a = stride(from: 0, to: 24, by: 1)
    var b =  stride(from: 0, to: 4, by: 1)
    var c = stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 2)
    var d = stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 2)
    var e = stride(from: 0.0, to: 0.5, by: 0.05)
}
```

I want to avoid nested loops if possible. i..e this isn't great:

```
let settings = Settings()
for v1 in settings.a {
 for v2 in settings.b {
  for v3 in settings.c {
   ...
    ...
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

would love to have something similar to `CaseIterable` which could provide all of the combinations

**Edit:**

Clarification. I have this implementation which loads everything

```
struct Settings {
    var a = 0
    var b = 0
    var c = 0
    var d = 0.0
    var e = 0
}

struct SettingsIterator: IteratorProtocol {
    mutating func next() -> Settings? {
        iter.next()
    }
    let range : SettingsRange
    var elements = [Settings]()
    var iter: IndexingIterator<[Settings]>
    init(range : SettingsRange) {
        // not lazy!
        self.range = range
        var arr = [Settings]()
        for a in range.a {
            for b in range.b {
                for c in range.c {
                    for d in range.d {
                        for e in range.e {
                            arr.append(Settings( a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d, e: e))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.elements = arr
        self.iter = elements.makeIterator()
        
        
    }
    
    typealias Element = Settings
    
    
}



struct SettingsRange {
    var a =  stride(from: 1, to: 5, by: 2)
    var b = stride(from: 1, to: 6, by: 2)
    var c = stride(from: 1, to: 5, by: 1)
    var d = stride(from: 0.0, to: 0.1, by: 0.1)
    var e = stride(from: 1, to: 4, by: 1)
}

extension SettingsRange: Sequence {
    func makeIterator() -> SettingsIterator {
        return SettingsIterator(range: self)
    }
}

let range = SettingsRange()
for s in range {
  print(s)
}
```

Comment: Also why would you want to iterate over different strides in nested loops? Please provide a real use case, since with the current overly simplified example, this seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I want to test each combination of the matrix where changing a single value each time. I.e. iterate each parameter and run a test

Comment: added an example - hope it is clearer